# What is the source of zombie zeppelin-spark processes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, zombie-process

When you have multiple people using Zeppelin (0.7.3) notebooks to prototype stuff on a cluster, you can end up with lots of [zombie processes](https://amandeepbatra.wordpress.com/2016/09/13/kill-those-zombie-zeppelins-spark-shells/) on the driver.

An example of what this looks like is here:

```
[username@usg-kov-e1b-mas001 ~]$ ps -aux | grep zeppelin
...
username  15163  0.0  0.0 783244 112076 ?       Sl   Aug29   0:16 /opt/zeppelin-env/bin/python /tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-294731840633169153.py 46864 10603
username  16364  0.0  2.3 4637180 2859000 ?     Sl   Aug29   1:30 /opt/zeppelin-env/bin/python /tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-4967700381049549623.py 34141 10603
username  17328  0.0  0.0 572336 68892 ?        Sl   Aug29   0:16 /opt/zeppelin-env/bin/python /tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5558242373873465119.py 43031 10603
username  23360  0.3  0.2 1029820 347676 ?      Sl   17:37   0:35 /opt/zeppelin-env/bin/python /tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5094022153210101706.py 35280 10603
username  26414  0.0  0.0 571972 68624 ?        Sl   Aug29   0:14 /opt/zeppelin-env/bin/python /tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1324142653437864728.py 46682 10603
username  28850  0.0  0.0 572332 68804 ?        Sl   19:23   0:01 /opt/zeppelin-env/bin/python /tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6914433048347435534.py 34529 10603
...
```

You can see they build up over time. Most of them only took a minute or two of CPU time, tops, but they don't go away. Over time, I've seen them chew up 10% or more of available memory.

Where do these come from? What is failing to clean these up? Is there anything (other than a process-murdering cron-job) that I can do the eliminate them?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [TimeoutLifecycleManager](https://medium.com/@zjffdu/zeppelin-0-8-0-new-features-ea53e8810235) which would terminate the interpreter if it is idle for the configured threshold

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I should have specified I'm still in 0.7. I aught to look into an upgrade.